# Is there a way to pathfind without a goal being concealed by closed nodes and still take hitboxes into account?

Tags: javascript, entity, nodes, path-finding

I am trying to program a game and I recently changed it from being grid based to allowing entities to move freely throughout space. This has caused a problem with the pathfinding algorithm, and I tried to fix this by making each node half the width of a "tile" and moving the center of the pathfinding map to the entity's location. Each entity, including nonmoving objects, has a hitbox defined relative to its coordinate position inside its class, in fractions of a tile:

```
this.hitbox = {
    x : -(5 / 16),
    y : -(3 / 16),
    w : (9 / 16),
    h : (3 / 16)
};
```

In order to pathfind, I create a square grid with each node being equivalent to a half tile, and set the size of the grid to be 4 * n + 1 tiles squared, with n being the entity's sense distance for the player (the target) in tiles. The center tile of the grid is set at the entity that is pathfinding's coordinates. This pathfinding is done using a getPath() function that inputs the entity that is pathfinding and outputs the direction that it should travel each frame towards its target.

```
function getPath(entity) {
    entity.targetFound = false;
    entity.pathfindingComplete = false;
    if(entity.targetAquired == true && entity.activeTarget.x > entity.x - (entity.senseDistance) && entity.activeTarget.x < entity.x + (entity.senseDistance) && entity.activeTarget.y > entity.y - (entity.senseDistance) && entity.activeTarget.y < entity.y + (entity.senseDistance) && !(isOverlap(entity.x - 0.1, entity.y - 0.1, entity.x + 0.1, entity.y + 0.1, entity.activeTarget.x + entity.activeTarget.hitbox.x, entity.activeTarget.y + entity.activeTarget.hitbox.y, entity.activeTarget.x + entity.activeTarget.hitbox.x + entity.activeTarget.hitbox.w, entity.activeTarget.y + entity.activeTarget.hitbox.y + entity.activeTarget.hitbox.h))) {
        entity.pathMap = [];
        entity.openNodes = {};
        entity.closedNodes = {};

        for(let i = 0; i < entity.senseDistance * 4 + 1; i++) {
            entity.pathMapRow = [];
            for(let j = 0; j < entity.senseDistance * 4 + 1; j++) {
                entity.pathMapRow.push({
                    x : j,
                    y : i,
                    walkable : true
                });
            };
            entity.pathMap.push(entity.pathMapRow);
        };
        for(let k = 0; k < entityList.length; k++) {
            if(entityList[k] != entity && entityList[k] != entity.activeTarget && isOverlap(entity.x - entity.senseDistance, entity.y - entity.senseDistance, entity.x + entity.senseDistance, entity.y + entity.senseDistance, entityList[k].x + entityList[k].hitbox.x, entityList[k].y + entityList[k].hitbox.y, entityList[k].x + entityList[k].hitbox.x + entityList[k].hitbox.w, entityList[k].y + entityList[k].hitbox.y + entityList[k].hitbox.h)) {
                for(let i = 0; i < entity.pathMap.length; i++) {
                    for(let j = 0; j < entity.pathMap[0].length; j++) {
                        if(isOverlap(entity.x + (j - (Math.round(entity.pathMap[0].length / 2) - 1)) * 0.5 - 0.25, entity.y + (i - (Math.round(entity.pathMap.length / 2) - 1)) * 0.5 - 0.25, entity.x + (j - (Math.round(entity.pathMap[0].length / 2) - 1)) * 0.5 + 0.25, entity.y + (i - (Math.round(entity.pathMap.length / 2) - 1)) * 0.5 + 0.25, entityList[k].x + entityList[k].hitbox.x - (entity.hitbox.x + entity.hitbox.w), entityList[k].y + entityList[k].hitbox.y - (entity.hitbox.y + entity.hitbox.h), entityList[k].x + entityList[k].hitbox.x + entityList[k].hitbox.w - entity.hitbox.x, entityList[k].y + entityList[k].hitbox.y + entityList[k].hitbox.h - entity.hitbox.y)) {
                            entity.pathMap[i][j].walkable = false;
                        };
                        if(i == Math.round(entity.pathMap[0].length / 2) - 1 && j == Math.round(entity.pathMap.length / 2) - 1) {
                            entity.pathMap[i][j].walkable = "startingNode";
                        };
                    };
                };
            };
        };
        entity.localKey = entity.pathMap[(Math.round(entity.pathMap[0].length / 2) - 1) + "x" + (Math.round(entity.pathMap.length / 2) - 1)]
        entity.openNodes[entity.localKey] = {
            x : Math.round(entity.pathMap[0].length / 2) - 1,
            y : Math.round(entity.pathMap.length / 2) - 1,
            parentNode : "startingNode"
        };
        entity.targetKey = (Math.round(entity.activeTarget.x * 2 - entity.x * 2) + (Math.round(entity.pathMap[0].length / 2) - 1) + "x" + (Math.round(entity.activeTarget.y * 2 - entity.y * 2) + (Math.round(entity.pathMap.length / 2) - 1)));
        entity.pathMap[Math.round(entity.activeTarget.x * 2 - entity.x * 2) + (Math.round(entity.pathMap[0].length / 2) - 1)][Math.round(entity.activeTarget.y * 2 - entity.y * 2) + (Math.round(entity.pathMap.length / 2) - 1)].walkable = true;
        console.log(entity.pathMap[Math.round(entity.activeTarget.x * 2 - entity.x * 2) + (Math.round(entity.pathMap[0].length / 2) - 1)][Math.round(entity.activeTarget.y * 2 - entity.y * 2) + (Math.round(entity.pathMap.length / 2) - 1)], entity.pathMap);
        while (Object.keys(entity.openNodes).length > 0 && entity.targetFound == false) {
            entity.neighborNodes = [];
            if(entity.openNodes[Object.keys(entity.openNodes)[0]].x > 0) {
                entity.neighborNodes.push(entity.pathMap[entity.openNodes[Object.keys(entity.openNodes)[0]].y][entity.openNodes[Object.keys(entity.openNodes)[0]].x - 1]);
            };
            if(entity.openNodes[Object.keys(entity.openNodes)[0]].x < entity.pathMap[0].length - 1) {
                entity.neighborNodes.push(entity.pathMap[entity.openNodes[Object.keys(entity.openNodes)[0]].y][entity.openNodes[Object.keys(entity.openNodes)[0]].x + 1]);
            };
            if(entity.openNodes[Object.keys(entity.openNodes)[0]].y > 0) {
                entity.neighborNodes.push(entity.pathMap[entity.openNodes[Object.keys(entity.openNodes)[0]].y - 1][entity.openNodes[Object.keys(entity.openNodes)[0]].x]);
            };
            if(entity.openNodes[Object.keys(entity.openNodes)[0]].y < entity.pathMap.length - 1) {
                entity.neighborNodes.push(entity.pathMap[entity.openNodes[Object.keys(entity.openNodes)[0]].y + 1][entity.openNodes[Object.keys(entity.openNodes)[0]].x]);
            };
            for(let k = 0; k < entity.neighborNodes.length; k++) {
                entity.currentKey = entity.neighborNodes[k].x + "x" + entity.neighborNodes[k].y;
                if(!(entity.currentKey in entity.openNodes || entity.currentKey in entity.closedNodes) && (entity.neighborNodes[k].walkable == true || entity.currentKey == entity.targetKey)) {
                    entity.openNodes[entity.currentKey] = {
                        x : entity.neighborNodes[k].x,
                        y : entity.neighborNodes[k].y,
                        parentNode : Object.keys(entity.openNodes)[0]
                    };
                };
                if(entity.currentKey == entity.targetKey) {
                    entity.targetFound = true;
                    break;
                };
            };

            entity.closedNodes[Object.keys(entity.openNodes)[0]] = entity.openNodes[Object.keys(entity.openNodes)[0]];
            delete entity.openNodes[Object.keys(entity.openNodes)[0]];
            if(entity.targetFound == true && entity.currentKey in entity.openNodes) {
                entity.closedNodes[entity.currentKey] = entity.openNodes[entity.currentKey];
                delete entity.openNodes[entity.currentKey];
            };
        };
        if(entity.targetFound) {
            entity.backtrack = entity.closedNodes[Object.keys(entity.closedNodes)[Object.keys(entity.closedNodes).length - 1]];
            while(entity.pathfindingComplete == false && entity.backtrack != entity.closedNodes[Object.keys(entity.closedNodes)[0]]) {
                entity.backtrackParent = entity.backtrack.parentNode;
                if(entity.backtrackParent == Object.keys(entity.closedNodes)[0]) {
                    if(wait == false) {
                        if(entity.backtrack.x > entity.closedNodes[entity.backtrackParent].x) {
                            entity.moveDirection = "right";
                        }else if(entity.backtrack.x < entity.closedNodes[entity.backtrackParent].x && entity.backtrack.y == entity.closedNodes[entity.backtrackParent].y) {
                            entity.moveDirection = "left";
                        }else if(entity.backtrack.y > entity.closedNodes[entity.backtrackParent].y) {
                            entity.moveDirection = "down";
                        } else if(entity.backtrack.y < entity.closedNodes[entity.backtrackParent].y) {
                            entity.moveDirection = "up";
                        };
                    };
                    if(entity.activeTarget.x > entity.x) {
                        entity.dirIndex = 0;
                    } else if(entity.activeTarget.x < entity.x) {
                        entity.dirIndex = 1;
                    };

                    entity.pathfindingComplete = true;
                } else {
                    entity.backtrack = entity.closedNodes[entity.backtrackParent];
                };
            };
        };
    } else {
        entity.moveDirection = null;
    };
    if(entity.targetFound == false) {
        entity.moveDirection = null;
    };
};
```

When it does this, it takes the sizes of the hitboxes of each entity, including stationary objects, and adds the distance from the corner of the pathfinding entity's hitbox to the object's hitbox size before checking if the new inflated size falls within each node. If it does, then the node is marked as closed. This is to make sure that the pathfinding entity's hitbox doesn't get caught on the hitboxes of other entities while it walks, keeping it away far enough to avoid this.

Then, the function retrieves the target entity's (often the player) node from its position relative to the pathfinding entity (enemy). It then uses a breadth first search to pathfind to it. The problem is that sometimes the player moves onto a node where all the nodes around it are marked as closed, because of the inflation of the entities' hitboxes to prevent the pathfinding entity from being stuch on a hitbox. This makes it so that if the player moves up next to an object, the enemy will freeze because it can't pathfind to the player.

Node diagram, the colored rectangles are hitboxes

[image]

I thought of opening all the nodes that were on the other side of the player from the red object, but that wouldn't work if the player was between 2 objects. Is there a way to solve this problem by changing this pathfinding method or using a better pathfinding method?

Comment: "Node diagram, the colored rectangles are hitboxes"... presume you meant to include a diagram with the question?

Comment: Yes, I'll fix it...